# Can USB-hubs just be stacked to the multiport or will it not receive enough power?

Tags: usb, usb-hub

The modern laptops don't have much USB ports anymore, if at all. So I have this multiport adapter (https://www.apple.com/nl/shop/product/MJ1K2ZM/A/usb-c-naar-digitale-av-multipoort-adapter) and (http://www.samsung.com/nl/mobile-accessories/multiport-adapter-pw700/). Those only have one USB, but we need one USB for wired keyboard, one USB for wired mouse, one USB free for USB sticks so we are short 2 USB ports. This must now become a common problem.

I know, I know everyone would now say simply go wireless, but in our case this is not an option.

Can USB-hubs just be stacked to the multiport or will it not receive enough power?

Comment: A powered USB hub would remove any power delivery concerns, but it would not be very portable.

Comment: It's not meant to be portable, it's meant to be stationary. It's going to be a flex workstation, connecting and disconnecting wireless devices is to much of an effort. We want to constantly connect the keyboard and mouse to the hub so anyone just needs to plugin one USB and it all works. So I am going to take your advice and look for a powered USB Hub.

Comment: It sounds like your ideal solution. A 4-port USB2 powered hub is very cheap, but you may like to consider something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Atolla-Powered-Splitter-Switches-Charging-7-port-USB-3-0-Hub-adapter/dp/B071QZ5D7L), which will give you a lot of future flexibility, such as having a permanently connected back-up disc.

Comment: I was looking at this one (https://www.bax-shop.nl/computer-accessoires/konig-powered-usb-3-0-hub-4-poorten-zwart?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhdfrnfP-1QIVjoeyCh0-0AfgEAkYAyABEgJA6PD_BwE) which is the same idea right?

Comment: Yes, it's the same sort of thing, but it has the minimum number of ports for your needs. The 7-port hub that I suggested gives you flexibility for future additions, and the individual switches are a useful feature for permanently connected USB-powered devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia [USB hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub) has the answer:

> A **bus-powered hub** (passive hub) is a hub that draws all its power
>   from the host computer's USB interface.
>
> A USB's electric current is allocated in units of 100 mA up to a
>   maximum total of 500 mA per port. Therefore, a compliant bus powered
>   hub can have no more than four downstream ports and cannot offer more
>   than four 100 mA units of current in total to downstream devices
>   (since the hub needs one unit for itself).
>
> **self-powered hub** is one that takes its power from an external power
>   supply unit and can therefore provide full power (up to 500 mA) to
>   every port.

Therefore, unless the multiport is self-powered, there is a practical limit
in what you can support.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, with some limits. All hubs in the chain must be powered hubs, except for hubs that have no other hubs (or devices that act like hubs) connected to them. You can't have more than five hubs in any one chain between the computer and a USB device. And you can't connect more than 127 USB devices to your computer at once, including hubs and any internal devices using the USB bus.

Comment: "You can't have more than five hubs in any one chain between the computer and a USB device." - Why do you believe this?  What I recall from my engineering classes when we discussed how USB work, I don't recall a limitation like this.

Comment: @Ramhound There are seven tiers available, but the host uses tier 1 and the client device uses the last tier, leaving up to five hubs in between. See for example this link: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-FBAFEFEA-A7EB-4012-8BFF-A06ED1F3000D.html